# hadoop: Reducer output to another Reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is it possible to send output of a Reducer directly to another reducer if we want to group by the same key ( output of the first reducer )

Sometimes while chaining i observe that i am using a mapper just to read from input and copy same to output. Hence wondering idf it is possible to fed the output directly to reducer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although you can chain map-reduce jobs, even mappers, together; as far as I know you can not chain reducers directly.

Internally you can chain mappers **before** reducer with [ChainMapper](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/ChainMapper.html) and chain Mappers **after** reducer with [ChainReducer](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/ChainReducer.html).